# Can't get field from Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I've tried to retrieve a saved picture URL from Firebase Firestore, but I'm keep getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'picURL' of undefined.

I've tried a code, which you can see below. It's from "imgRef" and down.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="posts">
   </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var postDocRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts')

postDocRef.get().then(snapshot => {
setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
})

const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

const setupPosts = (data) => {

    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {

        var docRefIDpost = docRef.id

        const post = doc.data();
        const li = `
        <li>
            <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
            <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
            <img class="img">
        </li>
        `;

        var imgRef = db.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts').doc(docRefIDpost);

        imgRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {

            const picURL = snapshot.data().picURL

            if (picURL.exists) {

            console.log(snapshot.data)

                console.log(picURL)
            
                    var imgpost = document.querySelector(".img");
        
                    imgpost.src = picURL
        
            }
            })
        


        html += li
    })

    posts.innerHTML = html;

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `snapshot.data()` returned undefined. As you can see from the API documentation, [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) will return undefined when the requested document was not found.  It's not clear here why, but your code should check for that **first** before accessing properties.

```
imgRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {
    const data = snapshot.data()
    if (data) {
        const picURL = data.picURL
    }
    else {
        // decide what you want to do if the document doesn't exist
    }
})
```